# How to implement persisent retry behaviour in Spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've been trying to develop such an algorithm in Spring Integration but it does not seem to work. The solution I have tried is (in pseudo-code):

```
GATEWAY (error-channel = "errorChannel")

CHANNEL (id="persistentDelayedRetryChannel")

CHANNEL (id="errorLoggingChannel")

ROUTER (input-channel="errorChannel")
  => if retryCount is not reached yet => persistentDelayedRetryChannel
  => else => errorLoggingChannel
```

So, the router listens for errors, and re-routes this message to the persistent retry channel if needed. Otherwise it logs an error and quits. Of course there are additional components involved, such as a header enricher which increments the retry count and a transformer which extracts the failed message from the Message{MessagingException} published to the error channel.

However, I am keeping getting the following error:

```
Reply message being sent, but the receiving thread has already received a reply:[Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException:....
```

Could anybody explain me why this is occurring and how to get  around it?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you delaying the retry? It means the thread that called the gateway has already received a reply of some kind (hasn't timed out).

Comment: Hi! I am delaying the retry with a spring integration delayer attached to the persistentDelayedRetryChannel and the gateway returns a Future object. That the thread has received a reply should mean that the future is "done" and has some result even if the retriable operation has not complated yet? If so, I will check what is returned there...

Comment: The fact you are using an Async gateway shouldn't make a difference; the async execution thread will still block until and actual reply is received (or we timeout) and it definitely looks like some response was sent to the `Future<?>`.